# MS Test giving inconsistent results for simple tests

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

The following tests are detected differently by the Visual Studio Test Explorer and have different output formats despite their similarities.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod("Test Method")]
    [DataRow("String#1", 1, DisplayName = "String#1-1 Display Name")]
    [DataRow("String#2", 2, DisplayName = "String#2-2 Display Name")]
    public void Test(string s, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{s}-{i}");
    }

    [TestMethod("Test Method with Dummy object")]
    [DataRow("String#1", 1, typeof(object), DisplayName = "String#1-1 Display Name")]
    [DataRow("String#2", 2, typeof(object), DisplayName = "String#2-2 Display Name")]
    public void TestWithDummy(string s, int i, object dummy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{s}-{i}-{dummy}");
    }
}
```

[image: Test Explorer Display]

The output for the method `Test` gives a separate Test Detail Summary for each DataRow.

The output for the method `TestWithDummy` uses the display name and displays a Test Detail Summary that shows all the results.

[image: TestWithDummy - Test Detail Summary]

Why would adding a dummy object parameter cause the second test to concatenate its results together? This looks like a far more useful output format.

I'm using VS2022 17.6.5, .NET 7, MS Test SDK 17.7.0, MS Test Adapter and TestFramework 3.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you found a bug. Looking around the MSTest repo I found one open issue that is very similar to yours: [TestMethod displayName is being ignored if DataRowAttribute is specified](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1635).

I'd suggest that you ask in that ticket if they consider what you found as the same bug, and if not, open a new ticket.